# Why does an Inpustream read method return an int?

Tags: java, buffer, arrays, inputstream

I'm trying to understand what is happening behind the scenes with the read method from an inputstream.

I know I can do the following:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("myFile.txt"));

byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

while(is.read(buffer) != -1) {
   // do something with the bytes
}
```

I believe this works by reading up to 8192 bytes into my byte array and then does something with those bytes.  But why does the read return an integer of the number of bytes read?  Is this purely so that whatever uses the bytes from the byte array knows when to stop looking for bytes?

I guess I'm confused because, for example, one of my reads shows

```
buffer[0] = 70
buffer[1] = 105
buffer[2] = 108
etc...
```

But if I'm reading up to 8192 for the entire byte array why are the elements in the array setup like this?

I realize this may be a dumb question, but I'd appreciate any help in understanding this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that thread is very helpful, thanks!  But I guess I'm looking for more details as to what is actually happening with the return values.

Comment: So for `buffer[0]` for example, it has `70` bytes that were read.  Why just 70 in `buffer[0]`?  Why wouldn't it max out to the limit of the read?  What causes it to put a `70` in the first element?  Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: No, `buffer[0]` will contain the first byte read in that call, which turns out to be `70`. If that is the only byte read, then the method will return `1`.

Comment: So `buffer[0] = 70` is a value that is interpreted by the calling stream (FileInputStream in this case)?  Is that how the jvm knows how to translate the bytes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your file is is stored on the disk. It is made up of bits, or bytes for our purposes. The first byte would have the base 10 value of 70.

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to ask my question as best I can with my limited knowledge.  Basically, what is `70` in `byte[0]`?  Is it a character, a number, or something else?  I don't have a strong understanding of data structures, so that is probably why I don't really get it.

Comment: It's not about data structures. The content of the file on the hard drive is stored as bytes. When you want to read the contents of that file, you need to read it byte by byte. That's what your `read(byte[])` call does. It reads byte by byte, setting each individual byte into a position in the array. The method then returns the number of bytes read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `is.read(buffer)` method reads either the maximum number of available bytes, or `buffer.length`(in this case, 8192) bytes, whichever comes first.

In the event that the entire array is not filled (which is possible because the number of available bytes may be less than `buffer.length`) it may be useful to have the number of bytes that *were* read so that the array can be safely iterated without throwing a `NullPointerException`.

The reason you are seeing

```
buffer[0] = 70
buffer[1] = 105
buffer[2] = 108
etc...
```

Is because in the stream of bytes being read, the first value is 70, the second is 105, the third is 108, and so on.  These are actually the *contents* of the stream, one byte at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Because, for whatever reason, it may not be able to read all of the bytes right now. So, the java VM returns the number it successfully read so you know what's going on.